# NRPE on solaris 8

Tags: gcc, solaris, cc, cl, nrpe

Hi there I was trying to install nrpe in solaris 8. I know that is very old hahah. But when I run ./configure, it shows me this.

./configure

checking for a BSD-compatible install... ./install-sh -c

checking build system type... sparc-sun-solaris2.8

checking host system type... sparc-sun-solaris2.8

checking for gcc...no

checking for cc...no

checking for cc...no

checking for cl...no

configure: error: no aceptable C compiler found in $PATH

There is a way to get this compilers or somenthing like that?

Thanks for support.

Comment: In the Bonus Software binder there should be a Software Companion CD. It has gcc on it. Package list at http://www.sunfreeware.com/programlistsparc8.html . I don't know if these CDs can be downloaded from Oracle.

Comment: Thanks for support, do you have any way to install gcc from tar.gz? or somenthing like that?. Greetings

Comment: If you have a tar.gz file, see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18118/how-can-i-view-the-contents-of-a-tar-gz-file-filenames-filesize) for how to view (t option) or extract (x option) it.